# .NET resource files - different fallbacks for different languages

Tags: .net, localization

In .NET it's easy to implement string resource files in multiple languages with a fallback if a string is missing in one language. Let's say I have resource files for english and french. I can set english as my default language and if a specific string is missing in the french resource file, the corresponding string from the english resource file will be used instead.

**But is it possible to have different fallbacks for different languages?**

For example, the fallback for a missing string in the french file is taken from the english file, but the fallback for a missing string in the spanish file is taken from the italian file.

And what if I want to fallback in multiple levels? E.g. No spanish - fallback to italian, no italian - fallback to english.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that is not possible. The .NET framework uses a hierarchy of cultures with the neutral culture at the root, neutral languages at the first level (e.g. French) and regional variations (e.g. French-France) at the second level. Fallback works up the hierarchy to the root, but not sideways. Technically, I think you could create a custom language, e.g. italian french, which would fall back to italian, but custom languages are more bother than they are worth. Your best bet is to translate all your texts to the right language.